# I have issue in RecyclerView setting text in particular TextView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am showing arraylist in recylerView. When i clicking particular recylerViewItem it will open bottemSheet in that beautician list show's when i am selecting particular beautician that beautician will be setTexted in textview in recyclerView. If i selecting another recylerViewItem in that i am selecting another beautician previous beautician getting cleared . So i don't want to previous beautician list should not be cleared.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
sessionManager = new SessionManager();
progressDialog = new MyProgressDialog();
try {
if(employee_data_value) {
if(btn_beautician_position_value == position) {
for (int i = 0; i < selectedEmployeeList.size(); i++) {
Log.d("EmployeeIds", "" + selectedEmployeeList.get(i).getStylistId());                      holder.mAutoLabel.addLabel(selectedEmployeeList.get(i).getEmployeeName());
}
}
}
}catch (Exception e){     
}       
holder.btn_add_beauticians.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {                   
apiViewBeauticians.ViewBeauticians(catDataList.get(position),position);
Log.d("ViewBeauticians", "Button :: ON_CLICKED");
}
});
}
```

Comment: it is because every time you select the item from the recyclerview you condition if(employee_data_value) will check and after that it will create the new instance of your StringBuilder thats why you are facing this issue.

Comment: here stringBuilder doing another work. only i have problem in settext

Comment: can you show the code so i can see your logic

Comment: okay editted the code please check